# Problems with bootstrap autocomplete plugin

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, autocomplete

Use this plugin: https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest

I'm trying load json file, but have some troubles with it.
If I try such construction :

```
$('#').magicSuggest({ 
  data: 'cities.json', 
  ajaxConfig: { 
    xhrFields: { 
      withCredentials: true 
    } 
  } 
});
```

get an error:

```
POST http://...../cities.json 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Uncaught Could not reach server
```

When i'm change:

```
ajaxConfig: { method: 'GET' }
```

and try to put some letters into input field got such error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

How can I fix this?